# POST doesn't write to database

Tags: ajax, django, django-views

I have my requestaccess view below, which will write to my database if I remove the if request.method == 'POST', but if i keep it in.  The request is never written. I'm trying to understand why the POST isn't occurring and how to make it happen?

```
def requestaccess(request):

    owner = User.objects.get (formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)

    reportdetail = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername, active = 1).values('report_name_sc')
    reportIds = QVReportAccess.objects.filter(ntname = owner.formattedusername).values_list('report_id', flat=True)
    checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')
    reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= checkedlist, active = 1).values_list('report_name_sc',flat = True)


    coid = User.objects.filter(coid = request.user.coid).filter(formattedusername=request.user.formattedusername)
    facilitycfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid , active = 1, cfo_type = 1).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
    divisioncfo =  QvDatareducecfo.objects.filter(dr_code__exact = coid, active = 1, cfo_type = 2).values_list('cfo_ntname', flat = True)
    selectedaccesslevel = '7'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectedaccesslevel = request.POST.get('accesslevelid')
        print(selectedaccesslevel)
    selectedphi = '0'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        selectedphi = request.POST.get('phi')
        print(selectedphi)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        for i in checkedlist:
            requestsave = QVFormAccessRequest(ntname = owner.formattedusername, first_name = owner.first_name, last_name = owner.last_name, coid = owner.coid, facility = owner.facility, title = owner.title
                                      ,report_id = i, accesslevel_id = selectedaccesslevel, phi = selectedphi, access_beg_date = '2017-01-01 00:00:00', access_end_date = '2017-01-31 00:00:00')
            requestsave.save()

    args = {'retreivecheckbox': reportlist, 'cfo7':facilitycfo, 'cfo5':divisioncfo, 'checkedlist':checkedlist }

    return render(request,'accounts/requestaccess.html', args)
#    return render(request, 'accounts/requestaccess.html', args)
```

My request.method == 'POST' statements never return the correct value only the hard coded one for a test.

My template requestaccess.html can be found below.  I can see the POST request for the ajax function being updated as i change the select options and when I click on the button.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

  {% block head %}
  <title> Access Request Form </title>
  {% endblock %}

  {% block body %}

    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h2>{{ user.username }}</h2></br>
          <ul>
            <li>Employee First Name: {{ user.first_name }}</li>
            <li>Employee Last Name: {{ user.last_name }}</li>
            <li>Coid: {{ user.coid }}</li>
            <li>Facility: {{ user.facility }}</li>
            <li>Title: {{user.title}}</li>

          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col">

  <form action = "{% url 'requestaccess' %}" form method = "POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
          <h2>Applications:</h3></br>

            {% for app in retreivecheckbox %}
            <li><input type="checkbox" name="report_id" value ="{{app.report_id}}" checked> {{ app }}
              </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>

      </div>


      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <label for="accesslevel"><h3>Access Level</h3></label>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select title ="accesslevelid" class="form-control my_select" id="accesslevelid">
            <option value=""> Please select your access level  </option>
            <option value="7"> Facility  </option>
            <option value="5"> Division  </option>
            <option value = "3"> Corporate  </option>
            <option value = "6"> Market  </option>
            <option value = "4"> Group  </option>
</select>

        </div>
        <div class="col">


          <label for="phi"><h3>PHI</h3></label>

          <select class="form-control my_select" id="phi" title = "phi" >
            <option value = ""> Please select if you need access to PHI data </option>
            <option value = "0"> No  </option>
            <option value = "1"> Yes  </option>

          </select>

        </div>
      </div>

        <div class="row">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
 </br> </br>

  <button href="{% url 'submitted' %}" class="btn btn-primary my_select" type = "submit"> Submit </button>
              <script>
          $(document).ready(function () {
              $('.my_select').on('change', function () {
                  var phi = $('#phi').val();
                  var accesslevelid = $('#accesslevelid ').val();
                  $.ajax({ url: "{% url 'requestaccess' %}",
                          headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}' },
                          data: {
                            phi: phi,
                            accesslevelid: accesslevelid,
                          },
                          type: 'POST',
                          success: function (result) {
                            ;
                          },
                        });
                });
            });
          </script>
</div>


  </form>

  {% endblock %}
```

Below is the console which shows the POST:

```
[07/Dec/2017 13:21:14] "GET /account/requestaccess/?report_id=84&report_id=87&report_id=88 HTTP/1.
3

[07/Dec/2017 13:21:22] "POST /account/requestaccess/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3928
3
1
```

After I click the submit button it gives me the following:

[07/Dec/2017 13:33:59] "POST /account/requestaccess/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3776
None
None

Edit:

Changing the javascript to on('click' instead of on('change' produces the same value of None.

Answer (score 3):

`checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')` is the culprit. You're populating that from the GET request, and when you POST, those aren't carried over in any way.

As a result, `checkedlist` is `None` and the save statement never fires.

Comment: How can I send that GET request to a POST in the same view? More ajax?

Comment: It's unclear from your question how you're using the GET request, but you'd need it to be part of the POST request that submitting your form produces. (So one way would be to use the GET request to prepopulate settings on the form, then posting those with whatever else the user selects on the form.)

Comment: My GET request comes from a page called Profile, where the user selects a collection of check boxes.  The URL of requestaccess includes the report_id = and the report name is passed to the template with check boxes pre-selected.  The user then changes some other options then pushes submit which is where the POST request should occur defined above with  <form action = "{% url 'requestaccess' %}" form method = "POST">.

Comment: report name is generated with the following:   checkedlist = request.GET.getlist('report_id')
    reportlist = QvReportList.objects.filter(report_id__in= checkedlist, active = 1).values_list('report_name_sc',flat = True), so that's how i'm using the GET there.   I'm new to this type of development so if my logic is incorrect or there is a better way to do it let me know.